# Downloading ZIP file with Ant

Tags: ant

I'm programming a script for download a .zip file inside an URL. My question is, how can I write a kind of wildcard such as `http://www.example.com/*.zip`.

This line get src="https://es.wordpress.org/wordpress-4.0-es_ES.zip" want to be like get src="https://es.wordpress.org/*.zip"

Comment: Anyone is invited to correct me, but wildcards are not supported by the HTTP and FTP protocol.

Comment: Mmmm, I supose it but I think that ANT can use any kind ow filters to do this.

Comment: The wildcard is supported by filesystem operation, but not for the Internet protocols. However, the wildcard is a type of filter, so there must somewhere a list to apply it. The url does always point to a single content item (as far as I know).